Second Order Differential Equation- Underdamped Spring-Mass System
I have a spring with a some mass, m oscillating up and down, hooked to a ceiling with a circular disc attached to the bottom.
Using newtons second law, $F = F_d + F_s$, where $F=ma$, $F_s = -kx$ (Hooke's Law), $F_d = -cv^2$ (Air Resistance, c is some constant)
We have $ma + cv\lvert v\rvert + kx = 0$ so, $m\ddot{x} + c\dot{x}\lvert \dot{x}\rvert+ kx=0$.
Is this solvable? What techniques could I use to try to solve this?
If it is helpful, $m=0.3345$ and $k = 27$, $c$ varies with diameter of the attached disc.

An discussion of the quadratically-damped harmonic oscillator via Mathematica can be found here, in particular in the absence of viscous damping (example 1). I very much doubt that even that case is amenable to an exact solution.

What specific information do you need out of the solution to this equation? Numerical techniques are very easy to use in many computing environments and can tell you a lot.

Didn’t spot that, thanks!
